# How do I recursively try different SSH passwords in Python?

Tags: python

We use multiple sets of predefined passwords here for test servers - I would like to try a portable Python SSH library (like the one below - spur.py) and get it to try each one in succession - but obviously stop when it is successfully connected or if it can't - ask me for a password. I'm after some sort of recursion with the exception handling I think.

```
def ssh_connection(user, host):
    try:
        shell = spur.SshShell(
            hostname=host,
            port=findport(host),
            username=user,
            password="abc123",
            private_key_file= expanduser("~") + "/.ssh/id_rsa",
            missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept
            )
        shell.run(["true"])
        return shell
    except spur.ssh.ConnectionError as error:
        print error
        raise
```

Coming from the Java world I'd check if the object is null and iterate through a list until the end and then ask for a password. I can't see how to do it in Python... Here's an example I found for the list part:

```
passwords = ['abc123', 'abc456',  'abc789']
for password in passwords:        # Second Example
   print 'trying password :', password
```

Comment: In the except part of the function just return `None` instead of `print` and `raise` then loop over it checking for that the value is not `None`.

Comment: why are you using both sshkeys and passwords at the same time ?

Comment: @JonathanVanasco the rest of the script deploys SSH keys to a server, so that is why I'm trying mutliple passwords - to get password-less logins.

Comment: @dueyfinster but this `spur.SshShell` argument doesn't make sense to me -- you're trying to connect with both a `password` and a `private_key_file`.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco I know from using SSH manually it'll try a key and then a password. I'm not sure if spur does the same, maybe it's hope more than anything....

Comment: Hmm I wonder what you're trying to do with this :)

Answer (score 2):

As Joe mentioned in the comments you can do something similar:

```
def ssh_connection(user, host, passwords):
    err = None
    for password in passwords:
        try:
            shell = spur.SshShell(
                hostname=host,
                port=findport(host),
                username=user,
                password=password,
                private_key_file= expanduser("~") + "/.ssh/id_rsa",
                missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept
            )
            shell.run(["true"])
            return shell
        except spur.ssh.ConnectionError as error:
            err = error
    if err:
        raise error
```

Comment: worked when I wrapped it - Thanks @Joe Doherty and yourself Ifthikan - I posted full code below for others.

Answer (score 0):

I would cut it in 2 different functions:

```
def ssh_connection(user, host, password):
    """
    try to connect to user:password@host
    return None if failed
    """

    try:
        shell = spur.SshShell(
            hostname=host,
            port=findport(host),
            username=user,
            password=password,
            private_key_file=expanduser("~") + "/.ssh/id_rsa",
            missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept
            )
        shell.run(["true"])
        return shell
    except spur.ssh.ConnectionError as error:
        print error
        return



def try_connection(user, host, passwords):
    """
    try all password in passwords to connect to host
    if all failed, ask for password via stdin
    """
    for password in passwords:
        conn = ssh_connection(user, host, password)
        if not conn is None:
            break
    else:
        # we never hit the break: ask for passwd
        password = ""
        while conn is None:
            print "please insert password for %s@%s (empty for exit)" % (user,host)
            password = raw_input("passwd:") # todo : insert Term seq for hide passwd and then restor
            if password == "":
                sys.exit(1)
            conn = ssh_connection(user, host, password)
    return conn
```

Answer (score 0):

My comment above got mangled, so here is @Joe Doherty suggestion used with code from Ifthikan - thanks!

```
def loop_ssh_connection(user, host):
        shell = None
        passw = ['abc123', 'abc456',  'abc789']
        while shell is None:
            shell = ssh_connection(user, host, passw)
        result = shell.run(["ls", "-l"])
        print result.output # prints ouput

def ssh_connection(user, host, passw):
    err = None
    for password in passw:
        try:
            shell = spur.SshShell(
                hostname=host,
                port=findport(host),
                username=user,
                password=password,
                private_key_file= expanduser("~") + "/.ssh/id_rsa",
                missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept
            )
            shell.run(["true"])
            return shell
        except spur.ssh.ConnectionError as error:
            err = error
    if err:
        raise error
```